# Send Contact via bluetooth in android

Tags: android

I am developing an Android application which needs a **Contact** to be transmitted from one android device to another via **Bluetooth**.
How to successfully transfer the contact?

Is there any efficient way to **transfer the Contact**?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739708/transfer-an-image-via-bluetooth-in-android) for the bluetooth transfer of images. You have to use the byteArray in case of transfering images via bluetooth.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0 , bos);
byte[] bitmapData = bos.toByteArray();  
bluetoothManager.sendDateToBTDevice(bitmapData);
```

You can go thro the *BluetoothChat* example in API demo n proceed wit that

Comment: Thanks, but I want to send Contact via Bluetooth.

Comment: I dont know whether there is any specific thing like sending business card thro' bluetooth. U can extract the contact info and send, then from there you can gather and make it as contact.